# Strange thing on PHP simple IF

Tags: php, mysql

In my code there is some IFs that all are the same and working, Except one!

Here is the code

```
<?php
if($tmp['data']=='0')
{
?>
some code...
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if($tmp['data']=='1')
{
?>
some code...
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if($tmp['data']=='a')
{
?>
some code...
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if($tmp['data']=='b')
{
?>
some code...
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if($tmp['data']=='c')
{
?>
 some code...
<?php
}
?>
```

$tmp['data'] is a value that is fetched from SQL database (varchar type).

IFs are working for all values, but when I set the value in phpmyadmin to 'c', related IF doesn't execute.

Any idea?

Comment: Show us what is in `$tmp['data']` when you set that `c` value, use f.e.x `echo $tmp['data'];`

Comment: If the related `if` doesn't execute, what does?

Comment: Sounds like there is an error in your code within the if($tmp['data']=='c'.  Try to comment out all of the code and just echo something and see if it works.  If so look for the error.  Also think about using a switch statement instead

Comment: Karol echo returns exactly the 'c' value.

Comment: Jamie nothing exceutes.

Comment: Chris I moved the c IF above the b IF. Still the same.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly isn't working? Also what is the exact output of: `var_dump($tmp["data"]);`?

Comment: Rizier123 the IF that is related to 'c' value is not working but the value is 'c'...var_dumb retrned: string(1) "c"

Comment: What does `echo mb_detect_encoding($tmp["data"]);` give you?

Comment: It returns ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use else if if more than one condition is never going to be true.

 to debug try to comment everything else and just keeping the if of c, make sure it is not case sensitive (eg. server may return C, but you may check for c)

Try this peice of code to see if it works (though its bit complicated)

```
  if( strcasecmp((string)$tmp['data'],"c")==0)
{ 
.. code here
}
```

Comment: I changed the c in the IF to uppercase. Still not working.

Comment: try this 'code' if( strcasecmp((string)$tmp['data'],"c")){ .. code here} 'code'

Comment: try to echo the tmp data variable to see if it actually contain c in it or not and then also add a echo for gettype(data variable) to really know whats happening

Comment: also try in the if instead of comparing it with character c, compare it with 99 (no qoutes around it, just 99)